# Relation between infinite product and regularized product

Tags: infinite-product, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

For a positive sequence $0<\lambda_{1}\le\lambda_{2}\le\cdots$, consider an infinite product
\begin{equation*}
    \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{i}:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}.
\end{equation*}
The product converges if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(\lambda_{i})$ converges.

Also, we consider the following zeta function given by a Dirichlet series
\begin{equation*}
    \zeta(s):=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{i}^{-s}.
\end{equation*}
We assume that the zeta function is absolutely convergent on some right-half plane, has an analytic continuation on $\mathrm{Re}(s)>-\epsilon$ for a positive number $\epsilon>0$, and is holomorphic at $s=0$.
Then, for this case, we define a regularized product by
\begin{equation*}
    \widehat{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{i}}:=\exp(-\zeta^{\prime}(0)).
\end{equation*}

My question is:

> If the ordinary infinite product converges, then does it coincide with the regularized product?, i.e. $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{i}=\widehat{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{i}}$$

The question is equivalent to the following:

> If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(\lambda_{i})$ converges, then $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(\lambda_{i})=-\zeta^{\prime}(0)?$$